# PDOK (Dutch geo-information) download package (Python)

Tags: python, gis

Is anyone aware of a Python package that enables the user to easily download raster or feature datasets from the Dutch NGR/PDOK? So for instance, based on a bounding box, download the appropriate AHN tiles. Or, retrieve BGT layers for a given area.

I haven't been able to find one on the usual places such as Github and/or PyPi, but I guess more people have been thinking about this.